# PhaserRexUI Plugin Not displaying

Tags: javascript, plugins, phaser-framework

So I've been trying to use the RexRainbow Phaser UI plugin, and All the Ui i make is invisible for some reason, But when I draw boundaries, it draws them, leaving me with a bunch of red boxes. Why are they all invisible?

[image: pic]

Code [Here](https://gist.github.com/VatsaDev/6eb312a6c83ccfa7a19a4cdb6a2bfb98) (Github Gist)

```
//UI
    var tabs = this.rexUI.add
      .tabs({
        x: 400,
        y: 1600,

        panel: this.rexUI.add.gridTable({
          background: this.rexUI.add.roundRectangle(
            0,
            0,
            20,
            10,
            10,
            0x4e342e
          ),

          table: {
            width: 250,
            height: 400,

            cellWidth: 120,
            cellHeight: 60,
            columns: 1,
            mask: {
              padding: 2,
            },
          },

          slider: {
            //scroll bar
            track: this.rexUI.add.roundRectangle(
              0,
              0,
              20,
              10,
              10,
              this.COLOR_DARK
            ),
            thumb: this.rexUI.add.roundRectangle(
              0,
              0,
              5,
              40,
              10,
              this.COLOR_LIGHT
            ),
          }
      .layout()
      .drawBounds(this.add.graphics(), 0xff0000); //debug for ui
```

`https://codepen.io/vatsadev/pen/dyqGNBG` -> full working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard too say, but I just can assume, that the reason is, that the color's used *(that are not visible)* are probally `undefined` and that's why transparent/invisible.

Without knowing the whole code, it is best to check, the **variables/properties** used for colors *(like: `this.COLOR_LIGHT`, `this.COLOR_DARK`, ...)*

**Especially** line 62, since here the `this` context is local to the `tabs`- object, and is not the `scene` object.

> ***Tipp:** for debugging purposes, I would hardcode all colors, just to see if the setup works, as intended. If so start replacing the hardcoded values with variables, like this you will find the culprit fast.*

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

const COLOR_PRIMARY = 0x4e342e;
const COLOR_LIGHT = 0x7b5e57;
const COLOR_DARK = 0x260e04;

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 283,
    scene: {
        preload,
        create
    }
};

var isLeaking = false;

function preload (){
    this.load.image('tiles', 'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/tilemaps/tiles/catastrophi_tiles_16.png');
    this.load.tilemapCSV('map', 'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/tilemaps/csv/catastrophi_level2.csv');
    
    this.load.scenePlugin({
      key: "rexuiplugin",
      url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rexrainbow/phaser3-rex-notes/master/dist/rexuiplugin.min.js",
      sceneKey: "rexUI",
    });
}

function create () {
    
            
    let map = this.make.tilemap({ key: 'map', tileWidth: 16, tileHeight: 16 });
    let tileset = map.addTilesetImage('tiles');
        
    let fgLayer = map.createLayer(0, tileset, 0, 0);
    
    createUi(this);

    updateMap(map);
}

function updateMap (map) {
    
    let originPoint1 = map.getTileAtWorldXY(200, 100);
    
    console.info(map.layers.sort((a,b) => b.depth - a.depth))

    map.forEachTile(function (tile) {
        var dist = Phaser.Math.Distance.Chebyshev(
            originPoint1.x,
            originPoint1.y,
            tile.x,
            tile.y
        );
        

        tile.setAlpha(1 - 0.09 * dist);
    });
    

}

function createDataBase () {
  var inventory = ['grass', 2, 'dirt', 3, 'wood', 2, 'leaves', 2, ]
  // Create the database
  var db = new loki();
  // Create a collection
  var items = db.addCollection("items");
  // Insert documents
  for (var i = 0; i < inventory.length; i+=2) {
    items.insert({
      blockType: inventory[i],
      quantity: inventory[i+1],
      color: Phaser.Math.Between(0, 0xffffff),
    });
  }
  return items;
};

function createUi(scene){
    var db = createDataBase();
    var tabs = scene.rexUI.add
      .tabs({
        x: 250,
        y: 250,
        panel: scene.rexUI.add.gridTable({
          background: scene.rexUI.add.roundRectangle(
            0,
            0,
            20,
            10,
            10,
            COLOR_PRIMARY
          ),

          table: {
            width: 250,
            height: 400,
            cellWidth: 120,
            cellHeight: 60,
            columns: 1,
            mask: {
              padding: 2,
            },
          },

          slider: { //scroll bar
            track: scene.rexUI.add.roundRectangle(0, 0, 20, 10, 10, COLOR_DARK),
            thumb: scene.rexUI.add.roundRectangle(0, 0, 5, 40, 10, COLOR_LIGHT),
          },

          createCellContainerCallback: function (cell) { // each inventory cell
            var scene = cell.scene;
            var  width = 250;
            var  height = cell.height;
            var  item = cell.item;
            var  index = cell.index;
            return scene.rexUI.add.label({
              width: width,
              height: height,

              background: scene.rexUI.add
                .roundRectangle(0, 0, 20, 20, 0)
                .setStrokeStyle(2, COLOR_DARK),
              icon: scene.rexUI.add.roundRectangle( // inventory item texture goes here
                0,
                0,
                20,
                20,
                10,
                item.color
              ),
              text: scene.add.text(0, 0, `${item.blockType}: ${item.quantity}`),

              space: {
                icon: 10,
                left: 15,
              },
            });
          },
        }),

        leftButtons: [
          createButton(scene, 2, "Inv."),
        ],

        space: {
          leftButtonsOffset: 20,
          leftButton: 1,
        },
      })
      .layout()
      .drawBounds(scene.add.graphics(), 0xff0000);
      
   tabs.on(
      "button.click",
      function () {
        // Load items into grid table
        var items = db
          .chain()
          .data();
        this.getElement("panel").setItems(items).scrollToTop();
      },
      tabs
    );
    tabs.emitButtonClick("left", 0);
}

function createButton (scene, direction, text) {
  var radius;
  switch (direction) {
    case 0: // Right
      radius = {
        tr: 20,
        br: 20,
      };
      break;
    case 2: // Left
      radius = {
        tl: 20,
        bl: 20,
      };
      break;
  }
  return scene.rexUI.add.label({
    width: 50,
    height: 40,
    background: scene.rexUI.add.roundRectangle(
      0,
      0,
      50,
      50,
      radius,
      COLOR_DARK
    ),
    text: scene.add.text(0, 0, text, {
      fontSize: "18pt",
    }),
    space: {
      left: 10,
    },
  });
};


new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lokijs/1.5.5/lokijs.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Changing the colors didnt affect the output, still the same as pic

Comment: @VatsaPandey the other thing, that could be an issue is maybe the `depth` ist to low. are you creating the UI before creating the map? you could try to switch it around.

Comment: no the Ui is made last, im trying to setup a working code snippet

Comment: https://codepen.io/vatsadev/pen/dyqGNBG

Comment: @VatsaPandey well there has to be something wrong with your code, I joined the codepen code with a map demo and it works, the only thing I had to do is to change the `x` and `y` value of the `tab` object, so that it is visible in the scene. I can't find anything else.